# Android- Want to show graphics for move an Object from one Point A to B

Tags: java, android, animation

I am new to make animation and graphics in Android. I am trying to create a Quiz type of game. and it is created . Now I am try to show the diff Levels(Level 1,Level 2...) to player. When a Player finish Level 1 , I want to move that Player Avatar to One Level 1 to Level 2 using some Animation(Ex: Like Candy Crush). Player Avatar moves to next level Automatically. Is there any Lib to animate is Avatar moving to  next level.

And is it possible to switch between my Quiz Game Activity and Game Level Screen using Libary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty general question so I can only suggest getting into [Android animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) tools. There right tool for the job is probably `PropertyAnimator` animating View (avatar) position as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. one more doubt, actually i have many levels. I cant show all levels within mobile screen. For ex: for user view i am showing first 4 level. for the 5th level, i want to move avatar(view) and background along with it(Which out of user view). i am so confuse with it. can you suggest any idea or some example for it?